# Can I use multiple NavHostFragments in Navigation Component?

Tags: android, android-architecture-components, android-architecture-navigation

Please look at the flowchart I made if you have difficulty in understanding the following paragraph.

I'm currently making a notes app with 3 top level destinations. One of the top-level destinations(NotesList) displays a list of notes created by the user. NotesList has a filter button which brings up a bottom modal sheet with FilterMenu destination. FilterMenu has a search button, which on clicking, replaces the contents of the sheet with a Search destination and a button named tags which on clicking, replaces the contents of the sheet with a fragment containing list of the tags associated with all the notes(TagList destination).

[image]

Everything in blue is a top level destination. Everything in purple is present in the modal sheet.

The FilterMenu, Search and the TagList are displayed in a modal sheet. Which means that the NotesList ***contains*** these fragments and is not replaced by them. They exist in a region of screen smaller than the NotesList. If I use navigation, the fragments will replace each other.

Can I use two NavHosts? One for the top-level destinations and one for the stuff in the modal sheet? If so, how would I implement it? If not, what's the recommended thing to do in this case?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You can create two navigation graphs to achieve the behavior you want. One for the top level destinations and a second one for the modal sheet. They need to be independent and do not have any links between each other. You can't use only one nav graph as the "navigation surface" is a different one. For the main navigation it's the activity and for the modal bottom sheet it's the bottom sheets window (which is in case of a BottomSheetDialogFragment actually a different window).

In theory this can be achieved very easily:

- `main_nav.xml` holds `Settings`, `NoteList` and `Trash`
- `filter_nav.xml` holds the `FilterMenu`, `Search`, and `TagList`

If you don't want back navigation on the top level you can even do the top level without a navigation controller using fragment transactions.

So basically you need a `(BottomSheet)DialogFragment` which needs an seperate `NavHost` independent from the main/other `NavHost`. You can achieve this with following class:

dialog_fragment_modal_bottom_sheet.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/filterNavHost"/>
```

ModalBottomSheetDialogFragment .kt

```
class ModalBottomSheetDialogFragment : BottomSheetDialogFragment() {

    override fun onCreateView(inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?, savedInstanceState: Bundle?): View =
        inflater.inflate(R.layout.dialog_fragment_modal_bottom_sheet, container, false)

    override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)

        // We can't inflate the NavHostFragment from XML because it will crash the 2nd time the dialog is opened
        val navHost = NavHostFragment()
        childFragmentManager.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.filterNavHost, navHost).commitNow()
        navHost.navController.setGraph(R.navigation.filter_nav)
    }

    override fun onCreateDialog(savedInstanceState: Bundle?): Dialog {
        return super.onCreateDialog(savedInstanceState).apply {
            // Normally the dialog would close on back press. We override this behaviour and check if we can navigate back
            // If we can't navigate back we return false triggering the default implementation closing the dialog
            setOnKeyListener { _, keyCode, event ->
                if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK && event.action == KeyEvent.ACTION_UP) {
                    view?.findNavController()?.popBackStack() == true
                } else {
                    false
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

We do two tricks here:

1. We need to manually create the `NavHost` fragment. If we directly put it into XML, it will crash the second time the dialog is opened as the ID is already used
2. We need to overwrite the dialog's back navigation. A dialog is a separate window on top of your activity, so the `Activity`'s `onBackPressed()` gets not called. Instead, we add a `OnKeyListener` and when the back button is released (`ACTION_UP`) we check with the `NavController` whether it can pop the back stack (go back) or not. If it can pop the back stack we return true and thus consume the back event. The dialog stays open and the `NavController` goes one step back. If it is already at the starting point, the dialog will close as we return false.

You can now create a nested graph inside the dialog and not care about the outer graph. To show the dialog with the nested graph use:

```
val dialog = ModalBottomSheetDialogFragment()
dialog.show(childFragmentManager, "filter-menu")
```

You could also add the `ModalBottomSheetDialogFragment` as `<dialog>` destination in `main_nav`, I did not test this though. This feature is currently still in alpha and was introduced in navigation 2.1.0-alpha03. Because this is still in alpha, the API might change and I'd personally use the code above to show the dialog. As soon as this is out of alpha/beta, using a  destination in `main_nav.xml` should be the preferred way. The different way to show the dialog makes no difference from a user's perspective.

I create a sample application with your navigation structure [here on GitHub](https://github.com/crysxd/NestedNavHostsExample). It has working back navigation on both levels with the two independent graphs. You can see it working [here on Youtube](https://youtu.be/lnyDB7DH9KM). I used a bottom bar for the main navigation, but you can replace it with a drawer instead.

Comment: @crysxd your solution works as advertised. However, is there no way to achieve this using more of the navigation sdk? I see you're using regular `<fragment>` instead of `<dialog>`, and you show the modal manually with `dialog.show()` instead of having navigation handle it. I feel like doing things manually like that kind of beats the purpose of using the navigation sdk

Comment: actually I got some other suggestion from Ivan Milisavljevic, see his demo https://github.com/milis92/Navigation-example I combined his use of <dialog> and modal fragment class with your runtime navhostfragment instantiation, and it seems to work well . Perhaps you can check out what he did and incorporate it in your answer, so we don't need the `dialog.show()` for example

Comment: Great to hear! That's what I meant with "You could also add the ModalBottomSheetDialogFragment as dialog destination in main_nav". Sorry for being not clear enough there! I updated the answer to improve this. The `<dialog>` destination is still in alpha and the API might change until it is in beta. IMO the difference between show() and navigate is minimal as it only affects this one line, so I'd personally stick with show for the time being. I can understand your desire to androidx-navigate all the things, though :)

Comment: I was about to add a code sample for the `<dialog>` destination but I decided to wait until this is in the stable release. I set myself a reminder to update this in 4 weeks! As soon as it's stable it is definitely the preferred way to open the modal

Comment: Alright fair enough. I try not to think about it too much because everything is alpha or beta these days

Answer (score 1):

An easy way to create two navHostFragments is to create another navigation.xml file.

In my app for example I have two navHostsFragments.

I defined the first one for navigation flow so when the user enters the app he goes to the login fragment which is the navHostFragment.

After user logs in he is transferred to the mainActivity which contains my new navHostFragment.

That way whenever I start a new activity that contains my new navHostFragment.

Hope this helps

Comment: I think your way only works because you have multiple activities

Comment: I have 3 activities for over 20 fragments so every-time I start a new big flow I create new activity, this is the only way I have found to have multiple navHostFragments.

Comment: alright, well, the person who asked this question and me have just one activitiy. The issue is specific to a fragment being modal as well as having to navigate from within that modal