# Fragment using children Fragments with Navigation Controller

Tags: android, kotlin, navigationcontroller

I have a query where I want to know whether it can be achieved or not with Navigation Controller.

#### Old Implementation

I have to take user info in multiple parts to make a smooth experience and keep the app a little interactive, now I have **Activity A** which contains two **Fragments A-1** and **A-2**. Now I show **Fragment A-1** and take part of the user info there and then on the next button I show **Fragment A-2** and take the remaining info there and then process the information to store it. Pictures are attached for a better understanding:

[image: Activity A with Fragment A-1]

[image: Activity A with Fragment A-2]

#### New Implementation Query

Now the question is that can all this be done with Navigation Component having a Fragment A containing two child Fragments A-1 and A-2 and transitioning from Fragment A-1 to Fragment A-2.

### Note:

I have recently started using the navigation component and have done a few simple examples as well as some nested graphs examples too but unable to do such tasks. I did this 2 years ago using FragmentManager but now I want to change the implementation to the best practices followed these days. Again I don't want to change the whole fragment but the child fragments (the middlebox where I take the user info) inside the parent fragment.

Comment: See if this helps: https://stackoverflow.com/a/56620939/2649154

Comment: I'll read and give it a try :)

Comment: I read and saw the video he posted but that is now what I am trying to achieve, he adds a dialog and when showing a dialog it opens on top of the fragment not in the fragment thus creating a black shadow behind it and I don't want that. I want to change the middlebox part where I take the info to transition from one to another fragment.

Comment: You can remove the black shadow.. Using a DialogFragment to host your "user info" window. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13822842/dialogfragment-with-clear-background-not-dimmed

Comment: I know about this, but is this a good approach?

Comment: If you want my opinion, I would use navigation for the details dialog(s). For me this is just a view. A way for the user to insert his details. It might change tomorrow.. I would have a view model for the screen and bind the view to the view model data.

Comment: Okay, l'll see if anyone else has another approach or I'll just use fragmentMangers again and bind them with the shared view model.